# How to disable all key of keyboard for online test module including combination key(ctr+esc) in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to disable all key of keyboard for online test module including combination key(ctr+esc) in php

Comment: can any one help me for same

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can't disable keys in php

Comment: You can disable text input, but you can't disable user keyboard, it would be so intrusive !

Comment: Do you mean disabling the keyboard on the browser machine entirely? Thankfully this is not possible.

Comment: #halfer u hav any answer or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in javascript, you can use:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: by this code single key is disable but not combination keys like windows key combined with other key or cltrl+esc key are not disable.

Comment: @PrashantSonar AFAIK it will disable all keyboard including ctrl+ combination.

Comment: is this funtion call on body's onload

Comment: @PrashantSonar I think that `document` is always present so this should work in any place.

Comment: OP asked how to do it in PHP!

Comment: I think more people need to appreciate humor in this website (@TobyAllen)